# How to Encode & Decode Url Containing Special Characters in QueryString?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am passing multiple parameters with the URL in the query string. parameter value contains special character like +,&, ,= etc.

How should I encode/decode the URL to get query string parameter values on the navigated page?

```
string myString = "Name=" + name.ToString() + "&SiteId=" + x.encrypt(Id.ToString());
Response.Redirect(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(myString));
```

Comment: A reason for downvoting the question in the comment section will help me in not repeating the same sin again.

Comment: You mention "Encoded changed X to Y..." but your question does not provide how that URL was encoded. Also, instead asking abuout multiple questions you should consider asking about more specific problems.

Comment: I have used 'HttpUtility.UrlEncode' as well tried with server.urlEncode.Anyways encoded URL was the same.

Comment: @sanjeev post your code then. You can't ask people to find the bug in your code if you don't even post that code. Most likely you encoded the *wrong* thing - after all, a value that contains the parameter separator `&` **can't** be part of a query string. It has to be encoded to `&amp`. `+` is used as a space separator in query parameters, so it can't appear by itself either.

Comment: There are no `Name` or `SiteId` parameters in the code you posted. It's a single invalid query parameter name without a value. You need to fix the client code so it encodes the parameter *values* before appending them to the URL.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos As I stated parameter 'Name' contains address so the address can have J&J square, J&K and same terms. for Id, I am using an encryption which convert '12345' to '+1kB0l3HI+ArTghSdB594g=='. So i am using HttpUtility.UrlEncode before redirecting to the next page. i haven't shared code by considering the precious time of my fellow developers so i directly shared the problem statement, though i have given case statement with erorr.

Comment: @sanjeev again, there's no `Name` parameter in the string you posted. Post your *client* code. You encoded the wrong string. You should have encoded the *individual values* only, not the entire URL.

Comment: Original Url was like "http://localhost:2398/SiteDetails.aspx?Name=NonLit-Hoarding-Guru+Ka+Taal+Flyover+Agra+Delhi+Highway-Transport+Colony-Transport+Colony-Agra-282007-Uttar+Pradesh-India-North+India&SiteId=nyAt4iTV9PQOcG1JTxuqWQ==" which after encoding resulted into "http://localhost:2398/SiteDetails.aspx?Name%3dNonLit-Hoarding-Guru+Ka+Taal+Flyover+Agra+Delhi+Highway-Transport+Colony-Transport+Colony-Agra-282007-Uttar+Pradesh-India-North+India%26SiteId%3dnyAt4iTV9PQOcG1JTxuqWQ%3d%3d".

Comment: It wasn't. That's not what you posted in the question. *Post the actual original URL, actual result, actual code*. The bug is in the client code. You can't fix that on the server, you'd only be replicating the bug and breaking *valid* URLs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205593/discussion-between-sanjeev-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Comment: There's no point in chatting. Post the code.Doing things *correctly* is actually simple - if you have just two parameters, you could even write `baseUrl + "&Name=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(name) + "&SiteId=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(siteId)`, or somewhat prettier, `$"{baseUrl}&Name={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(name)}&SiteId={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(siteId)}"`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Your Suggestion workout for me. I was encoding the whole url instead of a particular parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The First Mistake, I did was the encoding of the end URL instead of the query string parameter.

Encoding:

```
string myString = "Name=" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(name.ToString()) + "&SiteId=" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Id.ToString());
string Final_Url=HttpUtility.UrlEncode(myString);
```

Decoding:

```
QName = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.RawUrl.ToString()).Split(new Char[] { '?' })[1])["Name"];
QSiteId= HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.RawUrl.ToString()).Split(new Char[] { '?' })[1])["SiteId"];
```

Credit to @PanagiotisKanavos for giving me the right direction.